# 504(Gateway Time-out) on GET request

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, controller

I'm using Java, to execute GET request with HttpURLConnection to our server. (Timeout is infinity)

```
       HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
       con.setConnectTimeout(0);
       con.setReadTimeout(0);
```

The server configured as spring Controller and access the MySQL DB and run some queries.

In some of the cases, if the call takes 50 seconds, I get 504(Gateway Time-out) response from the server,
and in the server, there is an exception:
"org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: null .... Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset"

What is the reason for the timeout? 
It's in the Server side? or on the client side?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has it's own internal timeout settings. Try running the following sql queries against this database before running your other queries:

```
SET SESSION connect_timeout=300;
SET SESSION max_execution_time=300;
```

I believe these variables can also be set to 0 (infinity), although this may affect the stability of the service, and could influence other concurrent users (if there are any).